# How to extract string value from PySpark DataFrame field during when/otherwise processing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame where column `account_id` might hold either real account id or some alias (or representation) for account id. Also, I have a broadcast variable that holds Python dictionary inside, where keys keep all the aliases (representations) and values keep real account ids.

I want to process the dataframe so all the aliases (representations) will be replaced with proper account id. My idea is using when/otherwise and checking against Python dictionary from broadcast variable, so it should look like this:

```
    representation_dict = broadcast_repr.value
    representations = list(representation_dict.keys())
    result_df = df.withColumn('account_id', when(col('account_id').isin(representations), representation_dict.get(col('account_id')).otherwise(col('account_id')))
```

but I cannot do this because `col('account_id')` is of type Column and I can't use it to find a value in the dictionary, so I need to find a way to extract the exact value from this field. Is there any way to extract such value so I can use it with a dictionary?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: maybe make a new dataframe with that column only and using different kind of joins with your original dataframe?

Comment: yes, but it would be quite cumbersome because in this dataframe I have more than 10 columns holding such information

Comment: then add them all into one dataframe and call it like `ref_df`, which you can broadcast entirely for better performance.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample dictionary. sample values in the dataframe and expected results.